# No column was specified for column 1 of 'T1' when using a sub-select with a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, windows-server-2003

I have a working query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*), ACCOUNT_ID 
FROM 
    CDS_PLAYER 
GROUP BY 
    ACCOUNT_ID 
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1`
```

Output

```
No column name   Account_ID
----------------------------
    '2'          '12345'
```

I'm trying to add names to these accounts (all from the same table) but with no luck. The only query that gets me close is:

```
SELECT 
    LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, COUNT(ACCOUNT_ID) AS NUMBER
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(*), ACCOUNT_ID 
     FROM 
         CDS_PLAYER 
     GROUP BY 
         ACCOUNT_ID 
     HAVING 
         COUNT(*) > 1) AS T1
GROUP BY 
    LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, PLAYER_ID
```

But I get an error:

> No column was specified for column 1 of 'T1'

Like I said VERY NEW AT THIS. My boss of 4 months wanted me to learn and so I'm self taught (books and google). Any help at all to get me where I need to be would be appreciated!

(I'm using Windows Server 2003 and SQL Server 2000)

Comment: Looks like you need to give your COUNT(\*) an alias (column name). Try SELECT COUNT(\*) AS Cnt ... The rest should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error message can be resolved as below

```
SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, COUNT(ACCOUNT_ID) AS NUMBER
 FROM 
     (SELECT COUNT(*)  AS Total, ACCOUNT_ID FROM CDS_PLAYER GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID HAVING 
     COUNT(*) > 1) AS T1
GROUP BY LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, PLAYER_ID`
```

Add   `as TOTAL` after the `count(*)`

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT COUNT(*), ACCOUNT_ID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, PLAYER_ID
FROM CDS_PLAYER 
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, PLAYER_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

You should also update your version of SQL Server.  It is like 15 years out of date and hasn't been supported in many years.  You can download a free version of SQL Server Express from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

you want to select the `LASTNAME` and `FIRSTNAME`, but havn't it selected in your subselect. You only can access field which are in the *resultset*.

Solution: Add it to your `GROUP BY` clause.
ie:

```
SELECT 
    LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, COUNT(ACCOUNT_ID) AS NUMBER
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*), LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, ACCOUNT_ID 
     FROM CDS_PLAYER 
     GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME 
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS T1
GROUP BY 
    LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, PLAYER_ID
```